# Check if current page is author page in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, author

Is there a way I can check if the current WordPress page is the author page?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes... Or Maybe not ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure is `is_author()` - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_author

BTW, a little advice - This was the top link after putting you question title in google. Be sure to do your research first.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The thing is, I googled and tried is_author(), for some reason it didn't work, might be cuz I'm a little stressed out at work, cuz when I tried it again it worked perfectly! :)

Comment: Good! Take a break occasionally, sometimes the answer is staring you in the face. Glad it's sorted.

Answer (score 0):

`is_author()` is a conditional statement to check if an author page is being displayed. However I'm not 100% sure what you're looking for, so I suggest that you be more specific on what it is you wish to do exactly.

You can learn more about conditional tags [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags).